# Deduction of $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism for $\pi_{n+k}(E)\to H_n(B,Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is related to Milnor's Characteristic Classes, Cor 18.4. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of finite abelian groups. $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism means both kernel and cokernel finite. $Z$ below always denotes integer coefficients.

Cor 18.4 Let $E$ be an oriented rank $k$ vector bundle over a finite complex $B$ and $T$ be the Thom space of $E$. Then there is a $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism $\pi_{n+k}(T)\to H_n(B,Z)$ where $B$ is the base for all dimension $n<k-1$.

The book says it follows immediately from Lem 18.2 and Thm 18.3

Lem 18.2 If $E$ is an oriented rank $k$ vector bundle over $B$ and $t_0$ be the preferred base point(i.e. the point where pinch is,) then $H_{k+i}(T,t_0,Z)\cong H_i(B)$.

Thm 18.3 Let $X$ be a finite complex which is $k-1$ connected. Then $\pi_r(X)\to H_r(X,Z)$ is $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism for all $r<2k-1$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why Cor 18.4 follows from 18.2 and 18.3? My thought is the following and I do not see why I get a $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism. Assume conditions of Cor 18.4. Since $E$ is $k-1$ connected, by Thm 18.3, I have $\pi_{n+k}(T)\to H_{n+k}(T,Z)$ being $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism. Now consider $H_{n+k}(T,Z)\to H_{n+k}(T,t_0,Z)$ morphism. I do not know previous morphism is $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism. If I can check previous morphism is $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism, then I can conclude that total compoation $\pi_{n+k}(T)\to H_{n+k}(T,Z)\to H_{n+k}(T,t_0,Z)\cong H_k(B,Z)$ is $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism.

Comment: Notation would be simpler if you say that homology groups have integer coefficients and then omit $Z$ everywhere. BTW, in Lemma 18.2 you should have $H_i(B,Z)$.